# How to deal with "runtime error 50290" when using SetTimer API?

Tags: vba, excel, timer, crash

I've run into this error when trying to make a stopwatch timer in Excel. Here's a simple test code. Create an empty Excel workbook with a button. And assign a macro to it:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 0.5 * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub
```

Also, add this code to the module:

```
Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
    Range("A1") = "test"
End Sub
```

Then click the button and start clicking random cells. Shortly you will get the following window:

[image]

And after that Excel crashes.

What am I doing wrong?
How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with

```
On Error Resume Next
```

at the beginning of `TimerProc`. Some [more](http://www.cyberforum.ru/vba/thread948445.html) (in Russian) or [less](http://www.opclabs.com/forum/ua-reading-writing-subscriptions/1509-cell-update-in-excel-vba-gives-runtime-error-50290) related [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269844/api-timers-in-vba-how-to-make-safe).

Or probably even better:

```
Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
    On Error GoTo BeforeExit
    Range("A1") = "test"
BeforeExit:
End Sub
```

Comment: What might be happening was that you had clicked a cell and so Excel was in edit mode which means Excel stops & waits for you to enter something. This would probably block the code from writing to 'Range("A1")` and create the error.

Comment: Related: [Limitation of Asynchronous Programming to the Excel Object Model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2800327/limitation-of-asynchronous-programming-to-the-excel-object-model)

Answer (score 0):

I found using OnTime with current time will cause your code to run on the main thread immediately or fail. I found this better because you only need to trap the OnTime error.

```
Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal 
dwTimer As Long)
    On Error GoTo BeforeExit
    Application.OnTime Now, "updateWorksheet"
BeforeExit:
End Sub

Sub updateWorksheet
    Range("A1") = "test"
End Sub
```