# Application.ontime follow the wrong speed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to let a cell move on the screen every 0.9 seconds to 0.3seconds.

My code below only works every second for ms > 580 and in an extreme speed (every 0,01s?) for ms < 570.

Is something wrong with my speed calculation?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Gog()

Dim ra As Range
Dim ms As Long
ms = 580

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="GO", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

ra.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "GO"
ra.clearcontents

Application.OnTime (Now + (ms * 0.00000001)), "Gog"

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that perhaps OnTime only works to the nearest second..? So if mid-second, you advance on less time than it takes to set it to the *next* second, then it will run immediately as that second is already 'now'..?

Comment: Hmm very possible. What other function should I use?

Comment: See Ambie's response - that's the main alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.OnTime` doesn't operate at that level of precision. The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime) notes that:

> The value of EarliestTime is rounded to the closest second.

For greater precision than 1 second, you'll probably need to use the Windows timer, accessed via the API calls: `SetTimer` and `KillTimer`.

This SO post provides some examples of how to call the APIs (including the 64-bit versions) and explains some aspects to watch for: [API Timers in VBA - How to make safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269844/api-timers-in-vba-how-to-make-safe)